# Which method should i use to render a screen in a game?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

To practice programming I am making a simple 2d platformer game. (Basically a Mario clone).

The thing i'm having trouble with is knowing, which method should I use to render the picture on the screen.

For example, i have a background image, some platform tiles and a sprite which is the player's character. Each of them has a certain x y position set, on which it should appear.

My game loop will call a Draw() method 60 times per second (60fps) and each time, the screen will be cleared, updated and drawn.

Since i'm making the game in c# and wpf, i could just use something like grid, or canvas and position the pieces around with absolute positioning like in css basically. But that is probably not very performance effective.
So what is the default method to do this, which games like this usually use? (I am not using any Open GL or directX or any other libraries, all i have, are positions, on which the objects on the screen should appear, bunch of png pictures to represent these objects, and a wpf window to show them in)

Comment: Any reason for not using unity/mono/xna?

Comment: If you really want to do it in WPF exclusively, use `Canvas`.

Comment: I recommended you to use monogame for game creating.

Comment: @Sayse: Like i said, I'm doing it for the learning experience so i don't want to use any preprogrammed solutions.

Comment: @Fred - I can understand that, I'm just not sure what you would gain other than making your own game loop - which you can see the code for in xna (and I assume mono). You could always just create your own loop within wpf/gdi+ or similar to learn that and then continue from xna